# Converting an async method to return IObservable<>

Tags: c#, system.reactive, async-await

I have an `async` method that is a long-running method that reads a stream and when it finds something fires an event:

```
public static async void GetStream(int id, CancellationToken token)
```

It takes a cancellation token because it is create in a new task. Internally it calls `await` when it reads a stream:

```
var result = await sr.ReadLineAsync()
```

Now, I want to convert this to a method that returns an IObservable<> so that I can use this with the reactive extensions. From what I've read, the best way to do this is using `Observable.Create`, and since RX 2.0 now also supports async I can get it all to work with something like this:

```
public static IObservable<Message> ObservableStream(int id, CancellationToken token)
{
    return Observable.Create<Message>(
        async (IObserver<Message> observer) =>
            {
```

The rest of the code inside is the same, but instead of firing events I'm calling `observer.OnNext()`. But, this feels wrong. For one thing I'm mixing CancellationTokens up in there, and although adding the async keyword made it work, is this actually the best thing to do? I'm calling my ObservableStream like this:

```
Client.ObservableStream(555404, token).ObserveOn(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher).SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Subscribe(m => Messages.Add(m));
```

Comment: You should almost never use `async void`, certainly not in library methods.

Answer (score 13):

You are correct.  Once you represent your interface through an `IObservable`, you should avoid requiring the callers to supply a `CancellationToken`.  That doesn't mean you cannot use them internally.  Rx provides several mechanisms to produce `CancellationToken` instances which are canceled when the observer unsubscribes from your observable.

There are a number of ways to tackle your problem.  The simplest requires almost no changes in your code.  It uses an overload of `Observable.Create` which supplies you with a `CancellationToken` that triggers if the caller unsubscribes:

```
public static IObservable<Message> ObservableStream(int id)
{
    return Observable.Create<Message>(async (observer, token) =>
    {
         // no exception handling required.  If this method throws,
         // Rx will catch it and call observer.OnError() for us.
         using (var stream = /*...open your stream...*/)
         {
             string msg;
             while ((msg = await stream.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
             {
                 if (token.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }
                 observer.OnNext(msg);
             }
             observer.OnCompleted();
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }` be `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) { break; }` so that `OnCompleted` is called ?

Comment: @TiMoch no the observer has already unsubscribed in this case there is no need to send them any additional notifications

Answer (score 1):

You should change GetStream to return a Task, instead of void (returning async void is not good, except when absolutely required, as svick commented).  Once you return a Task, you can just call .ToObservable() and you are done.

For example:

```
public static async Task<int> GetStream(int id, CancellationToken token) { ... }
```

Then,

```
GetStream(1, new CancellationToken(false))
   .ToObservable()
   .Subscribe(Console.Write);
```

Comment: I think `GetStream()` fires an event several times, so `Task<int>` wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Yeah, the signature was an example, but in the edit, I am implying getting rid of GetStream by directly using ToObservable().  I am updating my answer with some clarifications.

Comment: Ah right, thanks. Yes, GetStream runs for ever and fires an event when it finds a message. So if I used `Task<Message>` instead, would that make sense? Would I ditch the event-firing in there for something else?

Comment: Sorry, you cannot use sr.ReadLineAsync().ToObservable() directly, otherwise it only reads one line.  I'm removing that suggestion.

Comment: @MattRoberts Yeah, that's a good possibility.  I was thinking of something else, but really I end up with something I don't like either.  I will have to think about it some more and maybe come up with something nicer later, otherwise I just get return Observable.Create<Message>(async o => {
                string text;
                while((text = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null) { 
                    o.OnNext(new Message { Text = text });
                }
                o.OnCompleted();
            });

Comment: @MattRoberts Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13161708/13131, it has more or less the same answer ... but with the CancellationToken included.

Comment: @MattRoberts Seems that TextReader.ReadLineAsync() is broken and not really asynchronous internally, so it's f'ng up everything I've tried.  However, this is kind of what I was going for (next comment), but haven't been able to hook up cancellation right, yet.

Comment: @MattRoberts public static IObservable<Message> ObservableStream(int id, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var sr = new StringReader("a\nb\n1\n2\nc\nd\n3a\nb\n1\n2\nc\nd\n3");

            return Observable.Create<Message>((o) =>         
                 (from line in Observable.Defer<string>(() =>  sr.ReadLineAsync().ToObservable())                       
                      where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && line.All(c => char.IsNumber(c))
                      select new Message { Text = line }).Repeat().Subscribe(o));            
        }